# How do I open a wifi network activity in portrait mode using intent?

Tags: android, android-wifi

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent)
```

It is starting wifi activity but screen get effecting when orientation changes

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "screen get effecting when orientation changes" means.

Comment: i want to fix that Wifi Screen to portrait mode..but it is turning to landscape when i turn the device..How can i make that?

Comment: @CommonsWare can u help me